# SQL CTE vs Temp table in terms of performance

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, temp-tables

The challenge: find all number triples `(n1, n2, n3)` from 1 to 512 such that `n1=n2*n3`. Using pure SQL only, and no pre-existing table spaces to expect, nor creating new permanent tables.

CTE solution:

```sql
;with two as 
(
    select 0 as ID union select 1 as ID
), eight as 
(
    select t1.ID*4+t2.ID*2+t3.ID as ID 
from two t1 inner join two t2 on 1=1 inner join two t3 on 1=1
), halfk as 
(
    select t1.ID*8*8 + t2.ID*8 + t3.ID + 1 as ID 
    from eight t1 inner join eight t2 on 1=1 inner join eight t3 on 1=1
) 
select t1.ID, t2.ID, t3.ID
from halfk t1 
inner join halfk t2 on t1.ID % t2.ID = 0 
inner join halfk t3 on t3.ID * t2.ID = t1.ID
```

Running time: Don't know; stopped after almost 2 minutes.

Temp table solution:

```
if (object_id('tempdb..#tmp_two', 'U') is not null) drop table #tmp_two
select 0 as ID into #tmp_two union select 1 as ID

if (object_id('tempdb..#tmp_eight', 'U') is not null) drop table #tmp_eight
select t1.ID*4+t2.ID*2+t3.ID as ID into #tmp_eight
from #tmp_two t1 inner join #tmp_two t2 on 1=1 inner join #tmp_two t3 on 1=1

if (object_id('tempdb..#tmp_halfk', 'U') is not null) drop table #tmp_halfk
select t1.ID*8*8 + t2.ID*8 + t3.ID + 1 as ID into #tmp_halfk
from #tmp_eight t1 inner join #tmp_eight t2 on 1=1 inner join #tmp_eight t3 on 1=1

select t1.ID, t2.ID, t3.ID as ID 
from #tmp_halfk t1 inner join #tmp_halfk t2 on t1.ID % t2.ID = 0 
    inner join #tmp_halfk t3 on t3.ID * t2.ID = t1.ID
```

Running time: 1 second.

**The question**: why is the performance so different? Why the CTE tables are not materialised even they were used more than once in the above solution?

More importantly, as the huge performance impact, how can I avoid using the clean and neat way to do the job but introducing performance hazard? Are there any guidelines to avoid cases like this?

```
select @@VERSION

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU10-GDR) (KB4293808) - 13.0.4522.0 (X64)   Jul 17 2018 22:41:29   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Comment: Because the CTEs are not being materialized, most likely.  You could go a step further and also consider indexing the temp tables, something not possible with CTEs.

Comment: Step 1: check the query plan (CTRL-L)

Comment: The query plan is not easy to read though. It is huge and the main cost are "Table Spool" and "Filter", which does not make much sense - "Table Spool" means temp table right?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't need to index the temp tables in the example above as they are small enough. Yet the temp table solution worked fine. My concern is: when I can be sure using CTE is without worse performance? As the increased readability, I would prefer it but I don't want to results in a slow query.

Comment: AFAIK in SQL Server CTEs are not materialized, and you would just be running the underlying queries directly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes with the last query and its second join. It has to make additional calculations and the row count just go over the roof. By understanding what you're trying to do, it's easy to avoid having the CTE being called a third time.

```
WITH 
two AS (
    SELECT 0 AS ID UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS ID
),
eight AS (
    SELECT t1.ID * 4 + t2.ID * 2 + t3.ID AS ID
    FROM   two AS t1
    CROSS JOIN two AS t2 
    CROSS JOIN two AS t3 
),
halfk AS (
    SELECT t1.ID * 8 * 8 + t2.ID * 8 + t3.ID + 1 AS ID
    FROM   eight AS t1
    CROSS JOIN eight AS t2
    CROSS JOIN eight AS t3
)
SELECT t1.ID, 
    t2.ID, 
    t1.ID / t2.ID AS ID
FROM   halfk AS t1
INNER JOIN halfk AS t2 ON t1.ID >= t2.ID AND t1.ID % t2.ID = 0;
```

CTEs don't materialize because they're just queries that have been refactorized to simplify reading and writing code, so every time they're called, they're recalculated.

You could even go with a more efficient way of creating a tally table.

```
WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E3(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b, E c
),
cteTally(ID) AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E3
)
SELECT t1.ID, 
    t2.ID, 
    t1.ID / t2.ID AS ID
FROM   cteTally AS t1
INNER JOIN cteTally AS t2 ON t1.ID >= t2.ID AND t1.ID % t2.ID = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for giving a better solution. However the algorithm is not the point of this question (I know it was dump). I am specifically looking for advises that predict the performance impact, so it can be avoided.

Comment: To predict performance, you need to consider number of rows, indexes available, CPU and memory available, and how will they be used. And even when you can have a great ability on predicting performance, something will happen against common logic. The only certain way is to test, test and test again.